# Sync Local Mysql databse to online Mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, winforms

I just uploaded my database to online server then my application successfully connected but suddenly my application goes too slow about 5 seconds delay in action and sometimes not responding.
To over come this, I think the solution is to sync my local database dynamically then connect my application to lacal database . .
My question is How can I sync local database to web server?

I'm using mysql and Ado.net as connector

With out using any third party software . .

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but if I understand, you want to syncronise a mysql database on a remote server, with the database on your local machine.

There are a number of ways to do this efficiently:

1. use mysqldump to make a backup of the data on your local machine, transfer the dump file to the remote server, via ftp/sftp/scp and then restore it on the remote server.

   mysqldump -u yourusername -p yourpassword yourdatabasename > yourbackupfilename.sql

and then run on the remote server

```
mysql -u yourusername -p yourpassword remotedatabasename < yourbackupfilename.sql
```

2. Use a mysql GUI (my favourite is sqlyog (https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog), but you have to pay for a license). sqlyog has a really nice feature where you can connect to both your local mysql installation, and the remote server. You can then copy databases from one to the other, all in the GUI. Super-convenient and easy, but method 1 will be faster for large databases.

If I misunderstood, please try to be clearer about what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you so much for you very nice answer sir . .Yes Got my point even my question is not clear.